# What signal formats are used for VSAT systems

Tags: electrical-engineering

Which signal formats do the VSAT communication systems use? I am currently reading the book "*Satellite Communications*" by Timothy Pratt but the content seems too confusing. Can anyone specifically tell me the names and types of signal formats used in VSAT systems?

[image: The content seems confusing]

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you found?

Comment: Yes, I have almost searched everywhere but I didn't found a particular answer specifically for this question. Btw, I know TDMA techniques are used in VSAT systems along with QPSK, BPSK, 8-PSK and others. But these are multiple access techniques if I'm not wrong. Then what are the "signal formats"?

Comment: @Adrian, are you looking for Data Communication format or the RF signal profile?

Comment: I don't know about that. I just want to know what signal formats do the author mean to say under this topic "Signal Format". Btw I think it would be data communication format only.